# Rails validate multiple attributes lambda only if all of them present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, attributes, lambda

I need to validate few attributes in my model only when they are present in `params` while updating or creating the object.

```
 validates :attribute_a,format: {with: /some_regex/},  :if => lambda{ |object| object.attribute_a.present? }
```

Like `attribute_a` there are multiple `attributes` which may not be present while being `created` or `updated`.Instead of writing the `validates` statement for each of them,is there a way in which I can check the presence of multiple attributes and then validate every one with a common validation such as `inclusion_in`or `format:{with:/some_regex/ }`.

I wanted something like the following code which obviously is wrong.

```
validates :attribute_a,attribute_b,attribute_c,attribute_d,:format => {:with =>
 /some_regex/},  :if => lambda{ |object| object.attribute_name.present? }
```

Comment: By present in this case you mean not blank (nil/"")?

Comment: The attribute is not present.So it is not nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`validates_format_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_format_of):

```
validates_format_of :attr_a, :attr_b, 
    with: /someregexp/,
    allow_blank: true
```

The allow blank option means that the regexp doesn't have to match if the attribute is not present.

Comment: Works.Silly question overall.My folly.